# How can I tell VS Code which of my installed standard library headers to use?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I use VS code, it takes hints from MSVC's standard library headers (they also can be seen by pressing "go to definition"), which [barely has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9eHT.png) any documentation comments or hints. However, GCC's standard library header source code has [much better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERIFW.png) documentation comments. I didn't find any settings or tasks that change this. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Are you sure you have that the right way around? GCC tends to not document because the C++ Standard library is [already well documented by other sources](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). MSVC on the other hand, they have a very deep-pocketed company backing them.

Comment: Not sure, but this comments are written in source code. I can see it by pressing "go to definition".

Comment: Yes they are in the header's comments, but it's generally Microsoft's headers rather than GCC's.

Comment: Interesting. I'm seeing that GCC has been commenting up over the past several versions. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you're not using CMake...

Write [a `c_cpp_properties.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference).

Quoting from the docs for the `compilerPath` property:

> The extension will query the compiler to determine the system include paths and default defines to use for IntelliSense.
>
> Putting `"compilerPath": ""` (empty string) will skip querying a compiler. This is useful if a specified compiler doesn't support the arguments that are used for the query, as the extension will default back to any compiler it can find (like Visual C). Leaving out the `compilerPath` property does not skip the query.

Quoting the docs for the `includePath` property:

> If on Windows with Visual Studio installed, or if a compiler is specified in the `compilerPath` setting, it is not necessary to list the system include paths in this list.

Note also that you can specify system include paths as a setting, `C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath`, with related docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp#_system-includes) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp#_system-include-pathdefines-resolution-strategies).

---

VS Code's various setup guides for C++ on different platforms / platform toolchain setups, they each have a section on how to configure the `c_cpp_properties.json` file for that toolchain+plaform combination. You'll find it really helpful, because each of those sections shows a code snippet of the basic setup.

Here are links to all the current toolchain+platform sub-pages at the relevant section (I'll inline the snippets for the Windows GCC ones just for you, but please do also check out those pages for up-to-date versions):

- [GCC on Windows via MinGW > C/C++ configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations)

  ```json
  {
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "GCC",
        "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
        "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }
  ```
- [Microsoft C++ on Windows > C/C++ configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_cc-configurations)
- [GCC on Linux > C/C++ configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_cc-configurations)
- [GCC on Windows Subsystem For Linux > C/C++ configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_cc-configuration)

  ```json
  {
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }
  ```
- [Clang/LLVM on macOS > C/C++ configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_cc-configuration)

#### If you *are* using CMake...

Use [the `vscode.cmake-tools` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools), and either instruct the extension to scan for [kits](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/kits.md) that can be found on your system, or set up (and [tell VS Code to use](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-presets.md)) a [CMake Presets file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) with where to find the compilers. Compilers usually know by default where their standard library headers are (if they come with them, which packages for compilers usually do).