# VS Code C++: cannot open source file "stdio.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

This issue started when I accidentally copied the folder which contained my .vscode folder.

So far, I have tried fixing this by
+Factory resetting my pc and redownloading vscode and cygwin
+C/C++ Configurations -> intellisense configurations-> intellisense mode = windows-gcc-x64
+C/C++ Configurations -> intellisense configurations-> Compiler Path->C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe

Quick fix tells me to edit compiler path under C/C++ configurations, which I believe I have done

My fixes are noted above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75425698/11107541 cc @KenWhite https://stackoverflow.com/a/77169094/11107541